# I tried to commit but it is showing this error

Tags: git, git-commit

```
git commit -m "reinitialized"
```

> fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken

Here is a screenshot of the full error:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have broken your Git repository. Do you know which commit (by hash ID) you would like to have as the tip commit for your `master` branch?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your git reference file is broken

to fix this you may need to remove your git reference file and run git fetch to get the references from the remote host.

delete reference file (

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD (replace head for the correct branch name)
```

fetch new reference from remote

```
git fetch
```